Seating assignment inspired question
Motivation. Recently I stayed at a hotel which had the curious custom to ask their $n$ parties (group of guests, most parties a married couple) which of the $n$ tables they wanted to take. Of course there were some "choice collisions" and therefore also some unpopular tables that nobody wanted. Luckily, in the end, a bijection was achieved, and everybody enjoyed a delightful evening. I spent part of the evening wondering, what the expected value of collisions, and of empty tables, were, assuming that the probability for each table to be picked was the same (and independent from party to party).
Formal version. Let $n>1$ be an integer, let $[n] = \{1,\ldots,n\}$, and let $\newcommand{\F}{\text{Fct}}\F(n)$ denote the collection of all functions $f:[n] \to [n]$. Note that $|\F(n)| = n^n$.
For any $f\in \F(n)$ let $\newcommand{\m}{\text{mp}}\m(f)=\max\{|f^{-1}(\{k\})|: k\in [n]\}$ be the maximum size that any fibre can have.
The expected maximum collision over all  $f\in\F(n)$ is defined by
$$\newcommand{\EMC}{\text{EMC}}\EMC_n = \frac{1}{n^n}\sum_{f\in\F(n)}\m(f),$$
and the expected range over all $f\in\F(n)$ is defined by
$$\newcommand{\ER}{\text{ER}}\ER_n = \frac{1}{n^n}\sum_{f\in\F(n)}|\text{im}(f)|.$$
Question. What are the values of $\liminf_{n\to\infty} \EMC_n/n$ and $\liminf_{n\to\infty} \ER_n/n$?

For ER, use linearity of expectation to get the answer $n(1-(1-1/n)^n)\sim (1-1/e)n$

Let's think of throwing $m$ balls into $n$ bins, in your case $m=n.$ When $m=n,$ the maximum loaded bin has load
$$
\frac{\log n}{\log\log n}\left(1+o(1)\right)
$$
with high probability. More precisely, the probability $p(\alpha,n)$ that there exists a bin with $\alpha \log n/\log\log n$ balls satisfies
$$
p(\alpha,n)=\left\{\begin{array}{lcl} 1-o(1),&\quad & \alpha \in (0,1), \\
o(1), &&\alpha >1.
\end{array} \right.
$$
The tools used include first and second moment methods (cf. The Probabilistic Method, popularized by Erdos), poisson and binomial tails approximation. There is a paper by Raab and Steger here which discusses the general case with $m\neq n.$ There,  the maximum load is with high probability equal to
$$
\frac{m}{n}+\sqrt{\frac{2 m \ln n}{n}(1-o(1))}
$$
where $o(1)$ goes to zero very rapidly, as soon as $m\gg c (\log n)^3 n$ while it is $c' \log n$ if $m=c n \log n.$
